# Western Digital WD7500BPKT not recognized as a WD drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, acronis-trueimage

I am in the process of upgrading my hard drive that is currently in my Toshiba Satellite Pro.
I have a WD 750 GB Black that I have hooked up SATA to USB and initialized, formatted and activated.
It is visible as drive E and all appears normal except that it is not recognized as a WD HDD.
This is important because I am attempting to use Acronis True Image software to clone my existing drive. When I try to install the Acronis software I am unable to do so because I get the message that I must have at least one WD drive on my system.

So how do I get my system to identify the drive as a WD HDD?

Comment: I assume your using a branded version of Acronis True Image that came with a WD drive instead of the version you purchase online?  Because the normal version of Acronis True Image works without a WD drive.

Comment: I'm guessing that formatting the drive removed whatever special identification there was on the drive. Did it come with an installation CD or something? If not you just might be screwed, and have to get another imaging software.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for the WD edition of Acronis TrueImage is that a WD drive be installed in the system during installation. An external drive doesn't meet the installation requirements. The drive is being correctly detected as not installed.

If your system has at least one IDE port and you can find any old WD drive, that will work. Once the software is installed, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you’re experiencing with your WD hard drive and Acronis software is due to the fact that the hard drive is connected to your computer via USB. When this is the case, Acronis retrieves the model name of the USB device through Windows’ underlying API calls, rather than the model name of the WD hard drive. This results in Acronis indicating that the WD hard drive is not installed.

To resolve this, you should connect the WD hard drive directly to your computer via a SATA connection. If your laptop doesn’t have two SATA ports, you could consider using [Renee Becca software](https://www.reneelab.com/data-backup/). This software allows you to directly clone the system hard drive or use the system migration function, without any restrictions related to the WD hard drive.